# how to recover all mysql tables of all databases in centos6 with mysql 5?

Tags: linux, mysql

mysql is corrupt in centos 6 it is showing

```
#1033 - Incorrect information in file: /xxxx/xxx.frm
```

for all database and showing all tables empty. how to recover all databases?

Answer (score 0):

- Check if an update did not messed up your my.cnf file. If the is a my.cnf.back, backup the actual my.cnf and rename the my.cnf.back to my.cnf. Try to restart mysql.
- Check if the line skip-innodb is in your /etc/my.cnf file. If it's the case, comment it and try to restart mysql.
- Check if you /tmp folder have the good rights (777). If it's not the case, use "sudo chmod 777 /tmp" and try to restart mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any reason to think the database files might really be corrupted? If so you need to restore from backups.

If not and you're using `innodb` for table storage then `innodb` may have failed to start. Check by starting up a mysql session and typing `SHOW ENGINES;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul & DeadEye,

My sql issue was due to innodb got disabled when server disk space got full.

This issue is resolved by following steps :
1) checked innodb with SHOW ENGINES;

Result :

```
 InnoDB     | DISABLED | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys
```

2) Enabled innodb by following steps :

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop

cd /var/lib/mysql/

ls ib_logfile*
mv ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.bak
mv ib_logfile1 ib_logfile1.bak

/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```